# Is there X-ref in Blender like maya?

Tags: animation

I want only one rigged charater to multi copy charaters by "Reference Editor" load[image]

Comment: It think it would be useful to include a description of what 'X-ref' is in case people are unfamiliar with the term.

Comment: X-refs aren't even a Maya construct, they're a 3DS Max construct. Please clarify your question by asking about the behavior you're trying to achieve, rather than an obscurely named feature from some other piece of software.

Comment: I'm so sorry guys // I attached Maya screen capture pic